How do we use abseil without CMake?
I have a C++ project where I need to use abseil strings library and abseil status library. However my project is large and is not using cmake at present, rather only a Makefile instead.
I have tried the following steps :

Cloning abseil from source
Doing the cmake and build
running make install DESTDIR=<some local dir>
using all the library files created above in the compilation command. i.e. I am linking all files like /local/lib64/libatlas_strings.a and so on.

However I am still receiving undefined reference errors during the linking phase. For example a snippet is attached below :
scratch/abseil-cpp/build/out/usr/local/lib64/libabsl_cordz_info.a(cordz_info.cc.o): In function `absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo::Head(absl::cord_internal::CordzSnapshot const&)':
cordz_info.cc:(.text+0x8a4): undefined reference to `absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle::DiagnosticsHandleIsSafeToInspect(absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle const*) const'
scratch/abseil-cpp/build/out/usr/local/lib64/libabsl_cordz_info.a(cordz_info.cc.o): In function `absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo::Next(absl::cord_internal::CordzSnapshot const&) const':
cordz_info.cc:(.text+0x98c): undefined reference to `absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle::DiagnosticsHandleIsSafeToInspect(absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle const*) const'
cordz_info.cc:(.text+0x9b3): undefined reference to `absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle::DiagnosticsHandleIsSafeToInspect(absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle const*) const'
scratch/abseil-cpp/build/out/usr/local/lib64/libabsl_cordz_info.a(cordz_info.cc.o): In function `absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo::CordzInfo(absl::cord_internal::CordRep*, absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo const*, absl::cord_internal::CordzUpdateTracker::MethodIdentifier, long)':
cordz_info.cc:(.text+0xf01): undefined reference to `absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle::~CordzHandle()'
scratch/abseil-cpp/build/out/usr/local/lib64/libabsl_cordz_info.a(cordz_info.cc.o): In function `absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo::~CordzInfo()':
cordz_info.cc:(.text+0xf76): undefined reference to `absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle::~CordzHandle()'
scratch/abseil-cpp/build/out/usr/local/lib64/libabsl_cordz_info.a(cordz_info.cc.o): In function `absl::cord_internal::CordzInfo::Untrack()':

Since I have included all the library files corresponding to absl here, I believe that the error is occuring due to incorrect ordering of the library?
Has anyone used absl without cmake? Any help would be appreciated.

The only two officially supported build systems for Abseil are Bazel and CMake.

So if I understand you correctly you want to use a plain Makefile for your own code, but are fine with using CMake for compiling abseil, you just don't want to use CMake in your own project when linking to it?

Have you considered making Abseil an external dependency instead of bundling it into your project?

Libraries need to be ordered with the "highest level" (users of symbols) first, and the "lowest level" (definers of symbols) later.  In the above situation we can see that the libabsl_cordz_info.a library is looking for the absl::cord_internal::CordzHandle definition, so you should figure out what library that is contained in, and put that library AFTER -labsl_cordz_info.  Another alternative if you don't want to bother with that is just list all the absl libraries twice on the command line.  Your link step will take longer but you won't have to dig into the ordering.

We need more information about how you are pointing your makefiles library search path with respect to the abseil artifacts

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your undefined reference errors (of which you have only shown us
a sample) mean either that your libraries are out of order
(libraries must appear in the linkage before those that they depend on)
or that you are not linking all that you need.
Since you are building with the abseil strings library and abseil status library, you must have installed the
abseil development package. (You don't say what your distro is, but e.g.
for Ubuntu that would be libabsl-dev .) Therefore you have installed the
libraries' .pc files and you can ask pkg-config
to tell you the linkage requirements for linking absl_strings and absl_status, including
the libraries they depend on and the order in which to link them.
~$ pkg-config absl_strings --libs
-labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -Wl,--push-state,--as-needed \
-latomic -Wl,--pop-state -lrt -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait \
-labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_raw_logging_internal \
-labsl_log_severity

$ pkg-config absl_status --libs
-labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal \
-labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle \
-labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_time \
-labsl_civil_time -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_optional_access \
-labsl_stacktrace -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_strerror \
-labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal \
-labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal \
-Wl,--push-state,--as-needed -latomic -Wl,--pop-state -lrt \
-labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 \
-labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_raw_logging_internal \
-labsl_log_severity

Here you can see, for example, that libabsl_status depends on labsl_strings, so at least you would
need to input them in that order to the linker.
Rather than type all that verbatim into your linkage options, just replace -labsl_strings
with the shell expansion:
$(pkg-config absl_strings --libs)

and likewise replace -labsl_status with:
$(pkg-config absl_status --libs)

in the linkage command, not forgetting that in Makefile context you will need to escape a shell $ as $$. You then stand a better chance of a successful linkage,
although as you haven't shown us what your current failing linkage is, or all its errors,
it may still fail.
You can also, incidentally, ask pkg-config to tell you the required compiler options for using these
libraries' header files:
$ pkg-config absl_status --cflags
-DNOMINMAX 
$ pkg-config absl_strings --cflags
-DNOMINMAX

